# VS Code Remote SSH Extension Reauthenticates and Fails to Reconnect After Opening Remote Directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I'm using VS code 1.81.1 on a Windows machine to connect to a remote Linux host. When I use the Remote-ssh extension in VS Code I can connect to a remote host, but when I try to open a remote directory within the remote host I'm prompted to reauthenticate with my password. Even after reauthentication, the extension fails to reconnect to the remote host, leading to a loop of password prompts.

My suspicion is that the extension might be trying to reinstall remote software upon each SSH session, causing conflicts when the software is already installed on the remote machine. The reason that I suspect this is that when I exit and restart the ssh session it fails to connect in the first place (whereas before it connected just fine, but wouldn't open any remote directories). If I then ssh via the terminal outside the Remote-ssh extension and then remove the remote software using

```
rm -r ./.vscode-server/
```

and then connect to the host through the Remote-ssh extension, then it works again.

I have tried changing different settings such as "Remote: Download Extensions Locally", "Remote ssh: Local server download", and "Remote ssh: server install path"

Changing any of these from the default just prevented my SSH session from connecting entirely.

Comment: Problem solved now. If anyone else is struggling with this, toggle the remote.SSH.useFlock setting and then remove the remote installation one more time.